# Multiple records associated with one id

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table that looks like this...

```
ID   | Cat Type |   LOB
ID_1 |  Cat_1   |   lob_1
ID_1 |  Cat_1   |   lob_2
```

That i want to look like this...

```
ID  | Cat Type | LOB
ID_1  Cat_1      LOB_1, LOB_2
```

How do I approach this in SQL?

Comment: What is your DBMS?  SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle?  Something else?

Comment: You essentially have a "vertical table". You could potentially use PIVOT and UNPIVOT to maneuver the data into the format you like

Comment: Ideally, you don't. If you're looking to eliminate *duplication* (of `Cat Type`) then it looks like you should be creating a *separate* table for `LOB`s. But you'd still have separate rows. Any column should only contain (for each row) a *single* piece of data.

Comment: As @Damien_The_Unbeliever says, you really don't want to do that. You might want to get a result set that looks like that, but you almost certainly do not want a table that looks like that final result.

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server aggregate string concatenation".

Comment: This sql query exists in a macro where I want my user to be able to see the data this way, its more intuitive to see how a catastrophe event might affect multiple lobs.  By what damien and you are saying... I shouldn't try this in sql it should happen in vba?

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic string aggregation query (which isn't so basic in SQL Server).  Here is one method that uses `outer apply`:

```
select id, cat_type,
       stuff(tt.lob, 1, 2, '') as lobs
from (select distinct id, cat_type
      from t
     ) t outer apply
     (select ', ' + LOB
      from t t2
      where t2.id = t.id and t2.cat_type = t.cat_type
      for xml path ('')
     ) tt(lob);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or without outer apply:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (
    ID nvarchar(4),
    CatType nvarchar(5),
    LOB nvarchar(5)
)

INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES 
('ID_1', 'Cat_1', 'lob_1'),
('ID_1', 'Cat_1', 'lob_2')

SELECT DISTINCT 
        ID,
        CatType,
        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + LOB  FROM @Table1 t WHERE t.ID = ID FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') as LOB
FROM @Table1
```